# Extract id from URL using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the 32 character id from the URL below:

```
https://digital-joshua.notion.site/84c7a26fb7aa4a0495a8e89a667a68a7?v=ceec49c8ec18473bbc1965ea17eb8868
```

This would be the intended output:

```
84c7a26fb7aa4a0495a8e89a667a68a7
```

✅ UPDATE:

@LukStorms solution achieves this:

\b[0-9a-f]{32}\b

Comment: What regex tool or language are you using?  The exact answer you need would depend on this.

Comment: Try [`[0-9a-f]{32}`](https://regex101.com/r/pIs0gM/1)

Comment: `\b[0-9a-f]{32}\b`

Comment: Thank you @LukStorms that worked! It results in 2 matches. 

I am very new to regex, curious to know if there's a way stop after the first match?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You haven't tagged an programming language. In javascript you can just not search global.  `/all/g` to find all all, versus `/first/` to only match the first first.

Comment: Or use a positive lookahead in this case:  `\b[0-9a-f]{32}(?=\?)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use a positive or negative look-behind so as to only return the string that we want.

- either we say that we want a slash `/` just before

```
(?<=\/)[0-9a-f]{32}
```

- or we say that we don't want an equals sign `=`

```
(?<!=)[0-9a-f]{32}
```